# How can I create a transition effect with winapi like css

Tags: html, css, winapi

I've been thinking about creating transitions using the Win32 API, like with CSS.

Here's the html code:

```html
<button class="btn1">Button</button>
```

Here's the CSS code:

```css
.btn1 {
    transition: .3s;
}

.btn1:hover {
    background: #000000;
}
```

How can I do something like this with the Win32 API?

Comment: It's possible but not necessarily easy. Windows has many technologies for this type of animation. One (modern) solution is to use WinUI3. You have an example of what you can do here: https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/winui-3-gallery/9P3JFPWWDZRC source is here https://github.com/microsoft/WinUI-Gallery with this you can use C/C++, C#, Rust (or other languages)

Comment: @Simon Mourier but i think WinUI3 needs xaml am I right? or it just works fine with raw winapi?

Comment: Yes, WinUI3 needs XAML. I don't see why this would be a problem, but if you want to use the original Win32 API, then there's not much builtin for that type of feature, you'll have to use GDI/GDI+, you can google for GDI GDI+ animation transition and see what you'll get back.

Comment: I suggest you could start from the Doc: [Animations and Transitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uxguide/vis-animations). And refer to the sample: [Windows Animation Samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uianimation/windows-animation-samples)

Comment: Oldschool Win32 API supports animation (fade transitions) for custom controls through [buffered paint animation API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uxtheme/nf-uxtheme-beginbufferedanimation).